# How do I get RTLD_LAZY behavior when taking the address of a function?

Tags: c, linux

We have a system that relies heavily on loading modules using [dlopen()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen). Our modules are self-describing, with a symbol that points to some metadata relevant to loading the module (description, load order, loading flags, etc.).

We first load the modules specifying the `RTLD_LAZY` flag to dlopen(), get what we need from the metadata, and then load the modules for real later (after we know what the load order should be, how they should be loaded, etc.).

This has worked pretty well for a while, but we've recently discovered that taking the address of a function requires that the function be resolved at load time. What are some ways we can work around this problem?

I've put together a fairly small example that demonstrates the problem.

```
/* foo.h */
void foo(void);

/* foo.c */
void foo(void) {}

/* bar.c */
#include "foo.h"
/* Calls foo normally */
void bar(void) { foo(); }

/* bam.c */
#include "foo.h"
static void (*f)(void);
/* Takes the address of foo */
void bam(void) { f = foo; }

/* rtld_lazy.c */
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void check(const char *module) {
  void *mod = dlopen(module, RTLD_LAZY);
  if (mod) {
    printf("%s successfully loaded\n", module);
    dlclose(mod);
  } else {
    printf("%s failed to load: %s\n", module, dlerror());
  }
}

int main() {
  check("./bar.so");
  check("./bam.so");
  check("./foo.so");
}
```

With the following output:

```
./bar.so successfully loaded
./bam.so failed to load: ./bam.so: undefined symbol: foo
./foo.so successfully loaded
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've come up with two methods for working around this problem, depending on the situation.

The first is in the caller's module, write a small static wrapper for the function. The static wrapper will dynamically bind to the function in question, and you can take the address of that function without any problems.

```
/* bam.c */
#include "foo.h"
static void (*f)(void);
static void foo_wrapper(void) { foo(); }
/* Takes the address of foo */
void bam(void) { f = foo_wrapper; }
```

If you find yourself writing lots of this tiny wrappers, you can instead put a function that returns the function pointer you need into the providing module.

```
/* foo.h */
void foo(void);
typedef void (*foo_ptr_type)(void);
foo_ptr_type foo_ptr(void);

/* foo.c */
void foo(void) {}
foo_ptr_type foo_ptr(void) { return foo; }

/* bam.c */
#include "foo.h"
static void (*f)(void);
/* Takes the address of foo */
void bam(void) { f = foo_ptr(); }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use dlsym() to obtain the address of a symbol. See POSIX :

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html

Comment: That's a good idea. In our specific case, though, that's not practical. Specifically, there's a compiler flag that can statically link everything together instead of using loadable modules. Thanks, though.